# How to jest mock a function living within another react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have been trying to write tests for the following react component which returns different components depending on my props:

```js
const Choice: React.FC<States> = props => {
    function getChoiceComponent(): JSX.Element {
        if (props.choices) {
            return <FirstComponent {...props} />;
        } else {
            return <SecondComponent {...props} />;
        }
    }

    return <>{getChoiceComponent()}</>;
};
```

How can I mock `getChoiceComponent` function and test it?

Comment: I don't think you can as it is in a closure.

Comment: define the function outside of the class and export it (thus being able to mock it) or define it on the instance itself and override it when testing

Comment: This is incomplete code, and appears to be unnecessarily complicated. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. If that function is part of a component currently under test why are you trying to mock it? It defeats the purpose of unit testing it if you don't actually test the real code.

Comment: I have updated the missing portion of the code.

Comment: Your question itself states that `write tests for the following react component which returns different components depending on my props`. Instead of mocking function, you should pass different values of props and check returned component

Comment: why is that function there at all? All the wrapper code here is basically unnecessary: `const Choice = props => props.choices ? <FirstComponent {...props} /> : <SecondComponent {...props} />` does the exact same thing in a single line.

Answer (score 2):

We should test the react component by changing the props and state rather than test the `getChoiceComponent` method directly. Here is the unit test solution,

`index.tsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import FirstComponent from './first';
import SecondComponent from './second';

type States = any;

const Choice: React.FC<States> = (props) => {
  function getChoiceComponent(): JSX.Element {
    if (props.choices) {
      return <FirstComponent {...props} />;
    } else {
      return <SecondComponent {...props} />;
    }
  }

  return <>{getChoiceComponent()}</>;
};

export default Choice;
```

`first.tsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';
const FirstComponent = () => <div>first component</div>;

export default FirstComponent;
```

`second.tsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';
const SecondComponent = () => <div>second component</div>;

export default SecondComponent;
```

`index.test.tsx`:

```js
import Choice from './';
import FirstComponent from './first';
import SecondComponent from './second';
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

describe('60152774', () => {
  it('should render first component', () => {
    const props = { choices: [] };
    const wrapper = shallow(<Choice {...props}></Choice>);
    expect(wrapper.find(FirstComponent)).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should render second component', () => {
    const props = {};
    const wrapper = shallow(<Choice {...props}></Choice>);
    expect(wrapper.find(SecondComponent)).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Unit test results with coverage report:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/60152774/index.test.tsx
  60152774
    ✓ should render first component (20ms)
    ✓ should render second component (5ms)

------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File        | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files   |   88.24 |      100 |      50 |     100 |                   
 first.tsx  |      75 |      100 |       0 |     100 |                   
 index.tsx  |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 second.tsx |      75 |      100 |       0 |     100 |                   
------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.065s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/react-apollo-graphql-starter-kit/tree/master/stackoverflow/60152774